# For loop problems

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to create a loop where the user enters some values for pizza toppings. They can have pepperoni, pineapple etc. When they type "done" I want it to break out of the loop. I have this all working. Its just my for loop which is the problem. I have 4 pizza topping, so naturally I put it to loop around 4 times. But if the user types in a wrong value, that uses up one of my 4 loops. Now I could set the counter to 200 so they are very unlikely to get it wrong that many times. But i'm hoping there is a cleaner version. So it will keep prompting the user until "done" is typed in. I tried using a while loop, with the do-while nested within it. Something like

```
   while( size != "done")
```

But that didn't work either. Hes my code :

```
 public List<String> Input(){
    List<String> toppings = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String size;

    System.out.println("What pizza toppings; Pepperoni, Fungi, Pineapple or Bacon, type 'done' when your finished: ");

FORLOOP:    for(int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++){

    do {
        size = sc.next();
        if ( size.equalsIgnoreCase( "Pepperoni") || size.equalsIgnoreCase( "Fungi" )  || size.equalsIgnoreCase( "pineapple" ) || size.equalsIgnoreCase( "bacon" )) {
            toppings.add(size);
        } else if( size.equalsIgnoreCase( "done" ) ){

            break FORLOOP;
        }   
        else{
            System.out.print("Choose either 'Pepperoni', 'Fungi', 'bacon' or 'pineapple' Toppings, type 'done' when finshed: ");

        }
    } while ( false );

    }
    return toppings;
}
```

Comment: "that didn't work". why not? it should.

Comment: I had a stackoverflow after typing in about 6 wrong values

Comment: nice when a SO brings you to SO.

Comment: `FORLOOP:` and `break FORLOOP;` Is this Java?  I'm legitimately asking... because I don't know.  I've never seen anything like that before.

Comment: Why are you using labels?

Comment: Try changing `while(false)` to `while(true)`, otherwise it will never repeat.

Comment: while( size != "done"), don't compare strings using == or !=, use .equals

Comment: Because strings should be compared using the `equals()` method, not object identity (!=).

Comment: When comparing strings in java, use `somestring.equals(otherstring)` instead of `==`, or `!somestring.equals(otherstring)` instead of `!=`.

Comment: A golden rule in programming is, don't make it any more complicated than at all necessary.  If for this rather basic case you actually need a labeled break, you need to start simplifying the thing right now :)

Comment: @nhgrif - Yeah, it is, but nobody ever uses it.

Comment: @JamesLoper I think your are using `break` inside `while` loop which is termination `while` loop and not `for` llop

Comment: I think that you should step back for a couple seconds take a breath and then try to re-evaluate what your logic is.  Why do you have a `do{...}while(false)`  If that's unintentional, than why does your while loop only break when you type `done`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int cnt = 0;

while(cnt < 4){
    size = sc.next();
    if ( size.equalsIgnoreCase( "Pepperoni") || size.equalsIgnoreCase( "Fungi" )  || size.equalsIgnoreCase( "pineapple" ) || size.equalsIgnoreCase( "bacon" )) {
        toppings.add(size);
        cnt++;
    } else if( size.equalsIgnoreCase( "done" ) ){
        break;
    }   
    else{
        System.out.print("Choose either 'Pepperoni', 'Fungi', 'bacon' or 'pineapple' Toppings, type 'done' when finshed: ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
while (toppings.size() < 4){
    size = sc.next();
    if ( size.equalsIgnoreCase( "Pepperoni") || size.equalsIgnoreCase( "Fungi" )  || size.equalsIgnoreCase( "pineapple" ) || size.equalsIgnoreCase( "bacon" )) {
        toppings.add(size);
    } 
    else if( size.equalsIgnoreCase( "done" ) )
    {
        break; //single depth. just break the while
    }  
    else
    {
        System.out.print("Choose either 'Pepperoni', 'Fungi', 'bacon' or 'pineapple' Toppings, type 'done' when finshed: ");

    }
}
```

(<s>add the break for 'done' yourself, but the object is clear.</s> * just make the guard something you actually need. like the size of the arraylist as I did here. You can use a count if you're getting the "ow noes, don't re-check the size in the loop" vibes :) )

*added the break.

Comment: so it loops until 4 toppings (it can be 4 times bacon) are chosen... where is the break on 'done'?

Comment: It is not there to make it simpler code, you can add it yourself (I thought), but I can add it for you if you want. Shouldn't be too much though...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the outer `for` loop or the `FORLOOP` label at all. Then just change the `while` condition to `true` so that it will loop forever until you explicitly `break;` when the user types in "done". Actually, instead of `break`ing, you could simply `return toppings` at that point.

If you're concerned about the user typing in the same topping twice, then either put the toppings in a `Set` -- `LinkedHashSet` will preserve order -- instead of a `List`, or check that `!toppings.contains(size)` before adding a `size` to the list. Incidentally, you might want to rename `size` to `topping` for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool wantMoreToppings = true;
bool shouldTakeMoreToppings = true;
while(wantMoreToppings && shouldTakeMoreToppings)
{
    String newTopping = sc.next();
    if ( newTopping.equalsIgnoreCase( "Pepperoni") || 
         newTopping.equalsIgnoreCase( "Fungi" )  || 
         newTopping.equalsIgnoreCase( "pineapple" ) || 
         newTopping.equalsIgnoreCase( "bacon" )) 
    {
        if(!toppings.contains(newTopping))//change this if you allow double toppings  
        {
           toppings.add(newTopping);
        }
    }
    else
    {
         wantMoreToppings = !newTopping.equalsIgnoreCase("done")
    }
    shouldTakeMoreToppings = toppings.size() < 4;//change this if you allow double toppings toppings
}
```